# JQuery data selector returning value + undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, undefined

I have a piece of jquery which drags the value from a page. One of the elements is a data attribute that is dynamically created dependent on form input. It returns the value but sticks 'undefined' infront of it on the first loop.

Relevent Code is as follows...

```
var get_files_split=get_files.split("*^*");
        var files_count=get_files_split.length-1;
        if(files_count!=0)
        {
            $('.uploaded_files').html("");
            var app_files="";
            for(var y=0;y<files_count;y++)
            {
                var files_split=get_files_split[y].split("|");
                app_files+="<div class='upfile_holder'>";
                app_files+="<div class='f_h'><span class='fil1'  data-this_file='"+files_split[0]+"'>"+files_split[1]+"</span> (<span class='fil5'>"+files_split[6]+"</span>)</div>";
                app_files+="<div class='f_h fil2'>"+files_split[2]+"</div>";
                if(files_split[4]!="")
                {
                app_files+="<div class='f_h'>&pound;<span class='fil3'>"+files_split[4]+"</span> <span class='fil4'>"+files_split[5]+"</span></div>";
                }
                if(files_split[3]!="")
                {
                    app_files+="<div class='f_notes'>";
                    app_files+="<p class='fil6'>"+files_split[3]+"</p>";
                    app_files+="</div>";
                }
                app_files+="</div>";


            }
            $(app_files).appendTo('.uploaded_files');
        }
```

This places the data on the page

JQuery that reselects the data is as follows...

```
var files_inform;
if($('.upfile_holder').length)
{
    $('.upfile_holder').each(function(){
            var file_ids=$('.fil1', this).data('this_file');
            var file_name=$('.fil1', this).text();
            var file_type=$('.fil5', this).text();
            var file_priority=$('.fil2', this).text();
            var file_price=$('.fil3', this).text();
            var file_tender=$('.fil4', this).text();
            var file_notes=$('.fil6', this).text();
            files_inform+=file_ids+"|"+file_name+"|"+file_type+"|"+file_priority+"|"+file_price+"|"+file_tender+"|"+file_notes+"*^*";
            alert(files_inform);
        });
}
```

The reason for reselecting the data is that the appended part is contained within a different function to when it is extracted.

Can't figure out why it is coming up as indefined.

Comment: `file_ids` prints up undefined for you ?

Comment: for the first instance it creates it starts with undefined plus the correct data attribute. All the other selectors work - example 'undefined234|first text|second text|etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem:-

```
var files_inform;
```

Should be -

```
var files_inform="";
```

Just by declaring the variable seems to mean this first state is undefined whereas declaring it as an empty means that it contains nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The `files_inform` variable is equal to `undefined` when the loop starts, and then you start appending string values to it. `undefined + "SomeString"` is `"undefinedSomeString"`. Initialise `files_inform` to an empty string:

```
var files_inform = '';
```

Comment: Thanks - just realised this hence my simultaneous post below :)